# pass request.user into form with ModelMultipleChoiceField , Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to pass request.user or request.user.pk from class based view to the ModelForm in order to filter query set with request.user.pk .
I have a following view:

```py
class ArticleResurrectionView(MessageLoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    model = Article
    form_class = ArticleResurrectionForm
    template_name = "articles/resurrection.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("articles:articles_main")
    redirect_message = "You have to be logged in to recover articles "

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = FormView.get_form_kwargs(self)
        kwargs["author_id"] = self.request.user.pk
        return kwargs
```

def get_form_kwargs(self): should pass  self.request.user.pk as a kwargs["author_id"]  to form’s **init**

Then I have following form for this view:

```py
class ArticleResurrectionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.author_id = kwargs.pop("author_id", None)
        forms.ModelForm.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)


    title = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label="Deleted articles", 

help_text="Please select the    article to recover", 

queryset=Article.default.filter(show=False, author=???) )

# I can not use self.author_id  here
```

Target is to use self.author_id from **init** in the title to filter queryset in a such way to show entries only made by current user. In another words I need to pass self.author_id  in the queryset in title.

Perhaps it is possible to do it by something  like that:

```py
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.author_id = kwargs.pop("author_id", None)
        forms.ModelForm.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.fields[“title"].queryset = ???
```

Anyway,  if you know how to get request.user in the queryset – I would be happy to get your solution on that.
Thank you!

p.s regarding Related managers:  "default" instead of standard "objects", i use 2 managers:

```py
class ArticleManager(models.Manager):
    """Shows only non deleted articles"""
    def get_queryset(self):
        return models.Manager.get_queryset(self).exclude(show=False)


class Article(models.Model):
    # related managers
    default = models.Manager() # shows all articles
    objects = ArticleManager() # shows only non deleted articles
.....
.....
.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second approach is indeed toe correct one, although you probably want to use a [**`ModelChoiceField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField) instead of a [**`ModelMultipleChoiceField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField), since the latter allows you to select *multiple* such `Article`s, but your form logic (`title`) hints that it is singular.

```
class ArticleResurrectionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    title = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Article.objects.none()
        label='Deleted articles',
        help_text='Please select the article to recover'
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        author_id = kwargs.pop("author_id", None)
        forms.ModelForm.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['title'].queryset = Article.objects.filter(
            author_id=author_id,
            show=False
        )
```

We initially thus specify the queryset to be empty, but later patch that by specifying another queryset in the constructor of the form.

As for your view, you probably want to make a `super()` call instead of calling the method of a specific class, like:

```
class ArticleResurrectionView(MessageLoginRequiredMixin, FormView):

    # ...

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['author_id'] = self.request.user.pk
        return kwargs
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it says: TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'queryset'

Comment: @AlekseiKhatkevich: can you edit your question with the *full* traceback?

Comment: @AlekseiKhatkevich: I think I found the issue. Fixed it in the answer.

Comment: It helped , thank you for your help and time. I prefer not to use super() method as it is les explicit then direct class call in my opition. From the other side it is more like choice of taste. I use ModelMultipleChoiceField to recover few articles at a time

Comment: it is also strange that DEBUGTOOL doesnt track SQL transaction in this case but it works regardless... just strange...

Answer (score 0):

Add request.user to your form instance

`form = FormItemForm(request.POST or None, request.user)`

Then in your form.py add this

```
field = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        queryset=Field.objects.none(),
        label='Fields',
        help_text='Please select a field.'
    )

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        us = args[1] or None
        forms.ModelForm.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['field'].queryset = Field.objects.filter(user=us)
```

Try that and see if it works. it worked well for me.